# Optimize the game in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

Optimization script doesn`t work. I made a script to optimize my game in unity, when the player is standing, everything is fine, But once it starts to go... Framerate Per Second starts to decrease to zero, tell me what should I do? After all, the player does not perform heavy operations, how can this load something? (I tried OnBecameVisible and OnBecameInvisible they don't work)

~Scripts~

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(ObjectParameters))]
public class ObjectManager : MonoCache
{
    public SpriteRenderer[] spriteRenderers;
    [Space]
    public ObjectParameters objectParameters;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] bool freezeRotation;
    bool isBuilded;
    [Space]
    public bool usingDragging = true;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] bool usingRigidBody;
    Rigidbody2D rb2D;
    float gS;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] bool usingSheetDrop;
    SheetDrop sheetDrop;
    

    void Start()
    {
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        objectParameters = GetComponent<ObjectParameters>();
        sheetDrop = GetComponent<SheetDrop>();

        if (usingRigidBody == true)
        {
            rb2D.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;
            gS = rb2D.gravityScale;
        }

        if (usingSheetDrop == true)
        {
            sheetDrop.enabled = false;
        }

        objectParameters.enabled = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < spriteRenderers.Length; i++)
        {
            spriteRenderers[i].enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "PlayerDrawing")
        {
            if (usingRigidBody == true)
            {
                if (rb2D == null)
                {
                    rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                }
                if (freezeRotation == false)
                {
                    rb2D.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;
                }
            }

            if (usingSheetDrop == true)
            {
                sheetDrop.enabled = true;
            }

            objectParameters.enabled = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < spriteRenderers.Length; i++)
            {
                spriteRenderers[i].enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "PlayerDrawing")
        {
            if (usingRigidBody == true)
            {
                if (rb2D == null)
                {
                    rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                }
                if (rb2D.constraints != RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll || rb2D.bodyType != RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic)
                {
                    rb2D.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;
                }
            }
        }

        if (usingSheetDrop == true)
        {
            sheetDrop.enabled = false;
        }

        objectParameters.enabled = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < spriteRenderers.Length; i++)
        {
            spriteRenderers[i].enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

*and ObjectParameters*

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectParameters : MonoCache
{
    public Dragging dragging;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Vector3 position;
    public Quaternion rotation;
    ObjectManager objectManager;
    Transform transform_;

    void Start()
    {
        objectManager = GetComponent<ObjectManager>();
        transform_ = transform;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public override void OnTick()
    {
        position = transform_.position;
        rotation = transform_.rotation;
    }
}
```

I wanted the script to work like this: When an object touches the *Player Drawing*, it turns on physic and *SpriteRenderer*, otherwise everything would happen in reverse. BUT IT DOESN'T WORK.
*help please*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any exceptions spamming into the console when you walk.
Also make sure to use the [Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) to see what method-calls are using the most of your framerate, you might have to turn on the deep profiler to see the exact methods.